# Symfony 6.3 - NelmioApiDocBundle : There is no extension able to load the configuration for "paths"

Tags: rest, jwt, symfony6, nelmioapidocbundle

I am trying to be authorized when trying out API routes through the API documentation created by [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://symfony.com/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/current/index.html). In this context, I have tried to configure the nelmio_api_doc.yaml file in order to get the JWT token needed for authorization. Here is its content:

```
# config\packages\nelmio_api_doc.yaml

nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: Books
            description: Une API d'OpenClassrooms avec des livres, des autrices et des auteurs !
            version: 2.0.0
paths:
    /api/login_check:
        post:
            operationId: postCredentialsItem
            tags:
                - Token
            summary: Permet d'obtenir le token JWT pour se logger.
            requestBody:
                description: Crée un nouveau token JWT
                content:
                    application/json:
                        schema:
                            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Credentials'
            responses:
                '200':
                    description: Récupère le token JWT
                    content:
                        application/json:
                            schema:
                                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Token'
        components:
            schemas:
                Token:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        token:
                            type: string
                            readOnly: true
                Credentials:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        username:
                            type: string
                            default: admin@bookapi.com
                        password:
                            type: string
                            default: password
            securitySchemes:
                bearerAuth:
                    type: apiKey
                    in: header
                    name: Authorization # or another header name
        security:
            - bearerAuth: []
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        path_patterns:
            - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc
```

However, I am getting this error message:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for "paths" (in "C:\Books\config/packages/nelmio_api_doc.yaml"). Looked for namespace "paths", found ""framework", "maker", "doctrine", "doctrine_migrations", "doctrine_fixtures", "sensio_framework_extra", "security", "lexik_jwt_authentication", "jms_serializer", "bazinga_hateoas", "nelmio_api_doc", "twig", "twig_extra", "web_profiler"" in C:\Books\config/packages/nelmio_api_doc.yaml (which is being imported from "C:\Books\src\Kernel.php").

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem with the indentation on the OpenClassRoom site. Try :

````
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        info:
            title: Books
            description: Une API d'OpenClassrooms avec des livres, des autrices et des auteurs !
            version: 2.0.0
        paths: 
            /api/login_check:
                post:
                    operationId: postCredentialsItem
                    tags:
                        - Token
                    summary: Permet d'obtenir le token JWT pour se logger
                    requestBody:
                        description: Crée un nouveau token JWT
                        content:
                            application/json:
                                schema:
                                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/Credentials'
                    responses:
                        '200':
                            description: Récupère le token JWT
                            content:
                                application/json:
                                    schema:
                                        $ref: '#/components/schemas/Token'
        components:
            schemas:
                Token:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        token:
                            type: string
                            readOnly: true
                Credentials:
                    type: object
                    properties:
                        username:
                            type: string
                            default: admin@bookapi.com
                        password:
                            type: string
                            default: password
            securitySchemes:
                bearerAuth:
                    type: apiKey
                    in: header
                    name: Authorization # or another header name
        security:
            - bearerAuth: []
    areas: # to filter documented areas
        path_patterns:
            - ^/api(?!/doc$) # Accepts routes under /api except /api/doc```
````

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Yet, it seems that you have forgot to put the closing apostrophes in lines 19 and 26 in your code. Would you mind checking that out?